# Using "not" and "no" with adjective

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I am not sure of using **no** and **not** in case an adjective follows. What is the right one between two examples below?

> Period of access providing (not longer than 1 year)
>
> Period of access providing (no longer than 1 year)

The usage of **no/not** with nouns is clear, but with adjective it is confusing.

Comment: What do you mean by "period of access providing"?  Also are the parentheses part of the sentence?  Could you please provide an example of the complete sentence, as this is just a fragment.  It would help us better understand the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I rephrase your sentence to something like *we provide a period of access (no / not) longer than 1 year*, then both versions are grammatical.

To me, *no longer* sounds more natural, while *not longer* seems more formal. However, that's mostly a personal opinion.

In terms of idiomatic use, [Google Books NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not%20longer%20than%2C%20no%20longer%20than&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20longer%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20longer%20than%3B%2Cc0) suggests that *no longer* is the more common of the two (at least in writing):

[image: (no/not) longer than]